# How to temporary save file in public folder in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i want to save a file temporary in public folder when browse the file.

That is when browsing file first save in public folder then i will read this file using `roo gem`, so please help me how to proceed it.

Answer (score 2):

For example like this

Form to upload file:

```
<%= form_tag some_path, :multipart => true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :my_file %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Upload' %>
<% end %>
```

In controller store uploaded file somewhere:

```
file = params[:my_file].read
filename = params[:my_file].original_filename
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'path', 'to', 'dir', filename), 'wb') { |f| f.write file }
```

Then process file with Roo when it is necessary and delete afterwards:

```
path = File.join Rails.root, 'path', 'to', 'dir', filename
rows = Roo::Spreadsheet.open path
for i in 0..rows.last_row do
   ...
end
File.delete path
```

You have to store filename somewhere. Or process all files in this directory. For example all xlsx files:

```
Dir.glob(File.join Rails.root, 'path', 'to', 'dir', '*.xlsx').each do |path|
  rows = Roo::Spreadsheet.open path
  ...
end
```

Actually you have to check whether file was uploaded before trying to store it, check whether file exists if you are processing file like in first example. But it is skipped to keep example simple.